# Is it possible to write a custom TouchBar app for an existing application?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nstouchbar

I have tried looking for an answer to this but can't seem to see anything about it.

I have a piece of software on my laptop (not written by me), that I want to customise. Some of the tasks I do are very repetitive, and could be simplified by just pressing a button on the Touch Bar that executes a number of commands.

Is it possible to write a Touch Bar app that either:

1) Customises the application's original TouchBar app (for which there is none)

2) Runs only when that application is running, and hides when the application is out of focus

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net/) can do that. [image]

Also in the "App Specific" button you can customise when to hide system touch bar and when to show it again